# Tried to remove Ubuntu, stuck with Grub

Tags: grub2, 13.04, uninstall

I need help. I tried to install ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8 on the same drive (a ssd) but all it gave me was problems-- boots in low-graphics mode, gives errors on start up, etc. etc. I'm done. So I go into windows to remove the two linux partitions, but I forget to expand the rest of the space. So now when I restart I'm booting into this grub rescue crap, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm using the live cd now.